# Kivy Won't Update Label While Reading from Microphone Using PyAudio

Tags: python, kivy, pyaudio

I am trying to update a Label in Kivy to say when the program is recording audio. I am having a problem where the PyAudio part takes over the thread and the text sent just before the record to the label doesn't update.

Update: the text "Recording..." is not appearing on the label.

Here is my code (that doesn't update):

```
self.answer.text = "Recording..." 
lib.record.record_audio()
self.answer.text = "Converting to text..."
```

And then I am using the standard PyAudio for recording:

```
import pyaudio
import wave

def record_audio():
    CHUNK = 1024
    FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
    CHANNELS = 1
    RATE = 44100
    RECORD_SECONDS = 5
    WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "output.wav"

    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                    channels=CHANNELS,
                    rate=RATE,
                    input=True,
                    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

    print("* recording")

    frames = []

    for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
        data = stream.read(CHUNK)
        frames.append(data)

    print("* done recording")

    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    p.terminate()

    wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
    wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
    wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
    wf.setframerate(RATE)
    wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
    wf.close()
```

Thanks

Update: Including full class call

The function in question:

```
def record_clicked(self, btn):
    self.answer.text = "Recording..."    #Doesn't display
    # uncomment the below line to input a new wave file 
    lib.record.record_audio()    #Takes 5 seconds
    self.answer.text = "Converting to text..."    #Doesn't display
    analyzed_tuple = lib.record.analyze_audio()   #Takes around ten seconds
    self.answer.text = analyzed_tuple[1]    #Displays
    self.search.text = analyzed_tuple[0]
```

Where it is called:

```
    record_button = Button(text="Rec.", size_hint=(0.15, 1))
    record_button.bind(on_press=self.record_clicked)
    top_layout.add_widget(record_button)
```

Comment: which text isn't showing up specificially? And which is?

Comment: I updated my answer, it is the first text "Recording..."

Comment: Is "Converting to text..." showing up? Does it seem like "Recording..." is being skipped?

Comment: Yeah, it takes 5 seconds and the text doesn't appear in that time.

Comment: Probably your function blocks the main thread. The gui can't update until your function(s) return (at which point it checks for input, updates the graphics etc.). Try running your code in a separate thread instead.

Comment: How could I do that? I am having a bit of trouble figuring it out.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Working-with-Python-threads-inside-a-Kivy-application) might help you when working with multiple threads in kivy